# Firebird CHAR_TO_UUID, failed with GDS Exception. 335544606

Tags: java, jdbc, firebird, jaybird

First background.

I am coding desktop application with Java as Eclipse RCP (efxclipse).
My configuration:

- Eclipse Mars
- efxclipse 2.0.0
- JDK 1.8_66
- Equinox OSGi framework
- Firebird 2.5.5.26952
- Jaybird 2.2.9
- HicariCP 2.4.1 as connection pooling solution

Database table example:

```
CREATE TABLE MYTABLE (
    ID  CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET OCTETS COLLATE OCTETS NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_MY_INDEX PRIMARY KEY,
    DATA VARCHAR(100)
);
```

HikariCP setup as

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
config.setDataSourceClassName("org.firebirdsql.pool.FBSimpleDataSource");
config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", cfg.getDbConnection());
config.addDataSourceProperty("user", cfg.getDbUser());
config.addDataSourceProperty("password", cfg.getDbPassword());
config.addDataSourceProperty("encoding", "UTF8"); 
//config.addDataSourceProperty("nonStandardProperty", "?octetsAsBytes=true?");
config.setMaximumPoolSize(cfg.getDbPoolSizeMax());

HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
ds.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
```

// I use UUID as primary keys and for get row I use code like

```
Connection con = ds.getConnection();
query = "SELECT DATA FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID=char_to_uuid(?)";
PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement(query);
p.setString(1, id);
```

where is "id" is string with value like '57F2B8C7-E1D8-4B61-9086-C66D1794F2D9'

Until last week I used Firebird 2.5.2xxx and Jaybird 2.2.8 on my computer and there are absolutely no problems with this setup. Then I have upgraded my firebird installation to version 2.5.5.26952 and problem appeared.

The problem:

After upgrading to Firebird 2.5.5 code part where I fetch row for known "id" throws exception

```
org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544606. expression evaluation not supported
Human readable UUID argument for CHAR_TO_UUID must be of exact length 36
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.internalExecute(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:782) ~[na:na]
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.executeQuery(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.PreparedStatementProxy.executeQuery(PreparedStatementProxy.java:52) ~[na:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.proxy.HikariPreparedStatementProxy.executeQuery(HikariPreparedStatementProxy.java) ~[na:na]
...
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.gds.GDSException: expression evaluation not supported
Human readable UUID argument for CHAR_TO_UUID must be of exact length 36
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.readStatusVector(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2092) ~[na:na]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.receiveResponse(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:2042) ~[na:na]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.wire.AbstractJavaGDSImpl.iscDsqlExecute2(AbstractJavaGDSImpl.java:1149) ~[na:na]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.impl.GDSHelper.executeStatement(GDSHelper.java:232) ~[na:na]
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.AbstractPreparedStatement.internalExecute(AbstractPreparedStatement.java:774) ~[na:na]
```

Value of "id" is string at 36 char length (I checked and it worked until last week). I have switched to Jaybird 2.2.9 problem still here.
As far as I understand this is related to something like sending parameters value as UTF8 string (length x 4) so I have altered my code looks like below:

```
p.setObject(1, id.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII));
```

Again, no result, same issue.

Also this may be something related with Jaybird connection parameter *octetsAsBytes* but I could not manage to apply it right (through HikariCP). 
I have tried

```
config.addDataSourceProperty("nonStandardProperty", "?octetsAsBytes=true?");
```

at HikariCP setup but result did not change.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me through plain JDBC (not using a DataSource or a connection pooler) using Firebird WI-V2.5.5.26952 and Jaybird 2.2.9.

Comment: Did the problem start with upgrading Firebird, or with upgrading jaybird? Note that for `nonStandardProperty` you should not include those questionmarks, although this property would not have any influence on the behavior here.

Comment: What happens if you try this with a single byte connection encoding, like win1252?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel problem started with upgrading Firebird

Comment: I'll see if I can reproduce it this weekend, maybe something changed in how the parameter is described for `char_to_uuid`. I have some theories as to what could be going wrong in either Firebird or in Jaybird. If you have time, could you check what happens if you use `char_to_uuid(cast(? as CHAR(36) character set ASCII))` (and also with `UTF8` instead of `ASCII`)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This works! Surprisingly with both ASCII and UTF8. Thank you very much. Although I do not if this counts as answer to my problem, if you write this as answer I would mark it as useful and correct.

Comment: I'd classify it as a workaround. It confirms my suspicion that something is wrong with either the width of the parameter or its character set. I am not yet sure if the problem is in Jaybird or Firebird though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: if something was wrong with the JDBC driver or Firebird, then why does this work for me with exactly those versions when using plain JDBC?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am not sure, I am trying to reproduce it right now. My theory is that it is caused by the connection character set (and then only if `UTF8` or another multibyte character set is used).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: a right. If I add `encoding=UTF8` to the connection properties I do get that exception (with Jaybird 2.2.8 and 2.2.9 - so it seems more like a Firebird issue)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interestingly enough, I haven't been able to reproduce it yet. It could still be a problem in Jaybird though, there are some issues in how it handles character set conversions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Correction, I can reproduce it but only if it is a primary key, which is curious to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this in Firebird 2.5.4, 2.5.5, and a recent snapshot of Firebird 3 (2.5.3 and earlier seem to be unaffected). I have been able to reproduce this and the problem seems to be in Firebird itself.

As commented earlier, a workaround is to cast the parameter to an explicit character set:

```
char_to_uuid(cast(? as char(36) character set utf8))
```

I have created a ticket in the Firebird tracker to report this: [CORE-5062](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-5062), and it will be fixed in Firebird 2.5.6 and Firebird 3 RC2